# How to access Email of an User on B2C using Graph API

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to know the email address of a user to send an email. 
On my application, people can sign up with social accounts (google/facebook/Microsoft) or local accounts.
When creating a local account we use the email.

I found this info about how email is stored. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies

> **Email address storage**: An email address can be required as part of a user flow. If the user authenticates with a social identity
>   provider, the email address is stored in the otherMails property. If a
>   local account is based on a user name, then the email address is
>   stored in a strong authentication detail property. If a local account
>   is based on an email address, then the email address is stored in the
>   signInNames property. The email address isn't guaranteed to be
>   verified in any of these cases. A tenant administrator can disable
>   email verification in the basic policies for local accounts. Even if
>   email address verification is enabled, addresses aren't verified if
>   they come from a social identity provider and they haven't been
>   changed. Only the otherMails and signInNames properties are exposed
>   through the Active Directory Graph API. The email address in the
>   strong authentication detail property is not available

Not sure why the field "Mail" on the user is not being used... but using GraphApi:

I make a GET: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/Users?$select=displayName,mail,otherMails,signInNames

Some emails appear on "mail", others on the array of "otherMails", and "singInNames" can't be selected :( doesn't show any info, so are some users that I can't get the info about the email.

How can I solve this? Only using *Azure AD Graph* instead of *Microsoft Graph API*, since on that API signInNames are returned?

Isn't there any way of storing the emails always on the same property? Or at least one that I have access on Microsoft Graph API? Using Custom policies only with Claims transformation?

Comment: you can get email as a claim in token also. What is your scenario?

Comment: I'm not authenticated as the User, is a server-side work that needs to send from time to time an email to all users of the platform

Comment: In the Microsoft Graph API the email of a local account is now returned in the **identities** property, but ONLY in the BETA version, not in the 1.0 version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to collect the email addresses from different places such as **mail**, **otherMails** and **signInNames** through AD Graph API. **signInNames** is **NOT** available in Microsoft Graph API.

Note that in the case where users sign in with username + email validation, there is no way to retrieve the email used.

Or you could add a [custom attribute in custom policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-create-custom-attributes-profile-edit-custom), where you can require users to type in their email address. After that, you could use AD Graph to get the custom attribute ([A sample here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet)).

Answer (score 11):

In the Microsoft Graph API you can use:

```
GET: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/Users?$select=displayName,mail,identities,otherMails
```

You can find the email of a local account in the **identities** collection.

In the BETA version of the Graph API (graph.microsoft.com/beta) the identities and otherMails properties are also returned without a $select, in the v1.0 version only when specified in the $select.

Comment: This is correct answer. However, I still wonder why this is so much complicated.

Comment: This works for me too, but having to check in multiple places for the email is far from ideal.

Answer (score 8):

I managed to get the email for a Azure B2C user through the following Microsoft Graph API call:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=identities

Answer (score 3):

The Microsoft Graph is the successor of the old Windows Graph. The Microsoft Graph doesn't support the `signInNames` property for `Users` object anymore. One has to filter on `identities` instead. However `identities` isn't part of the default property set of the `User` object so one has to select it. Once that's done, one can filter on identities using an `any` clause.

Note that filtering on `issuerAssignedId` can only be done when both `issuerAssignedId` and `issuer` are used in the filter clause.

```
GET: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/Users?$select=id,identities&filter=identities/any(c:c/issuerAssignedId eq '{email}' and c/issuer eq '{issuer}')
```